# How can i rewrite this url with a .htaccess file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, vagrant

can someone explain me how i can rewrite this url:

```
localhost:8080/log_reg/log_reg/index.php?page=register
```

to this:

```
localhost:8080/log_reg/log_reg/page/register
```

i'm using vagrant for testing

i already tested this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pages/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)?$ log_reg/index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
```

i know that this question is posted like 200x here. but i don't know how to get this working on my example... can anyone correct the htaccess-code?

**edit:**

the apache2.conf

```
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
# hints.
#
#
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#   /etc/apache2/
#   |-- apache2.conf
#   |   `--  ports.conf
#   |-- mods-enabled
#   |   |-- *.load
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   |-- conf-enabled
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   `-- sites-enabled
#       `-- *.conf
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
#   customized anytime.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.

ServerName localhost

# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /vagrant>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>




# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /vagrant

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very close. But at least you have to make sure that the slash is also optional:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /vagrant/
RewriteRule ^log_reg/page/([^/.]+)(/[^/.]+)?$ /log_reg/index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
```

Or the more relaxed version:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /vagrant/
RewriteRule ^log_reg/page/([^/.]+) /log_reg/index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
```

For that to work the file has to be located inside the outer `/log_reg` folder inside your `DocumentRoot`.

Here is the corresponding version for the host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /vagrant

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/log_reg/log_reg/page/([^/.]+) /log_reg/index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

In general you should prefer to place such rules inside your http servers host configuration instead of using `.htaccess` style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided for situations where one does *not* have access to the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting providers) or for applications that need to write their own rewriting rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: A very good place to start looking for a solution for such tasks actually is to take a look at the documentation of the rewriting module and check out the "rewrite logging" feature: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging It allows you to understand what exactly is going on inside your rewrite engine.

Comment: @arkasha if i enter this http://localhost:8080/log_reg/log_reg/page/register now i get an error with not found 404

Comment: Sorry, I missed the different spelling you yourself used in your question. There is a difference between `page` and `pages`. I fixed the answer.

Comment: There may be other things you will have to adjust, depending on your exact situation, but only you yourself have all information and can test things. As mentioned, rewrite logging is a _very_ helpful thing to track such things.

Comment: i dont' know why but i'm still getting the error 404. i placed the .htaccess in this folder http://localhost:8080/log_reg/log_reg/ but the vagrant serverroot is here: http://localhost:8080/

Comment: do i have to change the path in the htaccess file and move the file to localhost:8080 ?

Comment: I wrote in the answer that with the given code you need to place the file inside the outer `log_reg` folder inside the `DocumentRoot`. Obviously other setups are possible.

Comment: jeah but my document root is another one

Comment: do i have to place it here `localhost:8080/log_reg/log_reg/` or here `localhost:8080/log_reg/` ?

Comment: With the given code in the second option, just as I wrote. First option won't work, inside the `DocumentRoot` is possible, but the code has to be modified then.

Comment: Do you have access to the host configuration itself?

Comment: do you mean the apache.conf ?

Comment: Yep, that one, sure.

Comment: if so then i have

Comment: yeah i have access to that file

Comment: I suggest you place the rewrite rules in there, as written that causes much less issues and offers a better performance anyway. Would you mind posting the host configuration itself? Then we can help.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127645/how-can-i-rewrite-this-url-with-a-htaccess-file

Comment: i can't i only have 5rep

Comment: Ah, ok, sorry. Didn't see that.

Comment: 1. I said the relevant parts :-) 2. that is the wrong file, looks like your configuration is spread over multiple files. All fine! You see the inclusion command? (`conf-enabled/*.conf`) So look for the host you are using, that is what we are interested in.

Comment: i have 5 files in this folder... `charset.conf`, `localized-error-pages.conf`, `other-vhosts-access-log.conf`, `security.conf` and `serve-cgi-bin.conf` which one do you need ?

Comment: LOL, sorry, my fault this time. I obviously referred to `sites-enabled/*.conf`.

Comment: ahh here is a 00-default.conf

Comment: i think there is something wih the documentroot wrong

Comment: i had to change the `RewriteBase` to `/vagrant/`

Comment: I updated the answer and added the rule as required inside that host configurtion. As you can see things are much more obvious in there.